# Order of $a^m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \langle a \rangle$ a finite cyclic group of order $n$. Prove that $|a^m| = \frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)} = \frac{\mathrm{lcm} (m,n)}{m}$.

I managed "half" of it. Write $|a^m| = k$ and $d = \gcd(m,n)$. So I want to prove that $k = \frac{n}{d}$. Since both are positive, if I prove that $k \mid \frac{n}{d}$ and $\frac{n}{d} \mid k$, I'm done.

We have that $(a^m)^k = 1$, so $a^{mk} = 1$, and $n \mid mk$. This way, $\frac{n}{d} \mid \frac{m}{d}k$, and $\gcd\left(\frac{m}{d}, \frac{n}{d}\right) = 1$ gives us that $\frac{n}{d} \mid k$.

I'm missing something to get that $k \mid \frac{n}{d}$. Maybe I should try something using the $\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)}{m}$ part? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
(a^{m})^{\frac{n}{d}}=(a^{n})^{\frac{m}{d}}=1^{\frac{m}{d}}=1
$$

and thus 
$$
k\mid\frac{n}{d}
$$

Comment: Simple and clean. I knew I was missing something like this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @IvoTerek - Your'e welcome. You did the hard part yourself. It is general that to prove that the order of an element divide some number you raise the element by that number and show it is $1$